# Swift: Value of type 'string' has no member 'length'

Tags: ios, string, swift

I Have Implement Some TextField Functionalities in my App so I used TextField Delegates but it show some error like "Value of type string has no member length" I don't know how to solve this please help me for fix this issue.

Here I Give the Code of What I am trying.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    var oldLength: Int = textField.text!.characters.count
    var replacementLength: Int = string.characters.count
    var rangeLength: Int = range.length
    var newLength: Int = oldLength - rangeLength + replacementLength
    if textField.tag == 1 {
        if string.length > 0 && !NSScanner.scannerWithString(string).scanInt(nil) {  **------>//Error was showed in this line.**
            return false
        }
        // This 'tabs' to next field when entering digits
        if newLength == 5 {
            if textField == txtOtp4 {
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
        else if oldLength > 0 && newLength == 0 {

        }

        return newLength <= 4
    }
    else {
        if newLength == 11 {
            if textField == txtPhoneNumber {
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
            return newLength <= 10
        }
    }
    return true
    // This allows numeric text only, but also backspace for deletes
}
```

Comment: why are you using `string.length` in one line but `string.characters.count` in the other?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Replace

```
if string.length > 0
```

by

```
if string.characters.count > 0
```

**Edit for Swift 4:**

`String` now conforms to the `Collection` protocol, so it has a `count` property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tim Vermeulen.

Comment: It's Works but it shows new issues.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: New Error in same line.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: The error is ScannerWithString is unavailable: use object construction 'NSScanner(String:)'

Comment: So then replace `NSScanner.scannerWithString(string)` by `NSScanner(string: string)`. The error message was really descriptive, I'd advise you to see if you can solve something by yourself first, before you ask others.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Swift 2.0, you should use

```
string.characters.count
```

to get the number of characters in the String.